# How to handle API request limit in python?

Tags: python, api, python-requests-html

Is there a way to stop a program after the API request limit is met? If so, how to do it?
Do you just count the request number, each time you make an API request? For example, like this:

```
while request_count <= 100:
   data = requests.get('url').json()
   request_count += 1
else:
   break
```

Comment: What is the API here? Sometimes the server may return a specific key in the header.

Comment: You can try rotating proxies and ip addresses: https://www.scrapehero.com/how-to-rotate-proxies-and-ip-addresses-using-python-3/

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you could do, but we need more information on your side about what API you're using, and what you're calling.

- The API itself may have a key to pull how many requests you have already used. Ideally, you'll ping that and check before you make a request.
- Many API's send an error message when you hit your limit, so you can review the JSON response with `data.json()` and see if it's a rate limit request, in which you then can exit the program.
- If both of those are not possible with the API, I would recommend using your database to track that and update it each time you make a request like Mongo. Could also be as simple as a text file. This seems very convoluted if the API provides no information about your rate limits.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for attempting to answer a question. However, your answer here really isn't an answer. It is asking more questions of the OP, and should be placed as a comment on the OP's original question.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thanks for the feedback. Maybe, it would've been better to show code on how to handle rate limit errors, show an example of a route to check api routes, or a basic example of storing pings?